# How to found the problem of Device crash log in Iphone

Tags: iphone

I am new one to develop iphone App. so help me to found out error in crash log. In crash log contains only library or framework. Help me to found out crash line .

Comment: You will need to include more specific information about the nature of the crash.

Comment: what kind of information to include?

Answer (score 1):

Check the crash log and find the memory address where it is crashed .
(see MyApp  **0x35626f5a** 0x1000 + 22516)

Crash log:

0 WebCore   0x35626e8a 0x3023d000 + 23455

1 Foundation    0x3565ebf8 0x3023d000 + 56767

...     ... ...

17 MyApp    **0x35626f5a** 0x1000 + 22516

Steps to analyze crash report:

1. Copy the .app file and the .dSYM file that was created at the time of release to a folder (say CrashTest).
2. Open the Crash report.
3. Open 'Terminal' application and go to the folder (CrashTest) created above (using CD command).
4. Use this command :atos -arch armv7 -o 'app_name.app'/'app_name' 'crashed_memory_location'.
       (crashed_memory_location ->The memory location should be the one at which the app crashed as per the report).

   ```
   Eg : atos -arch armv7 -o MyApp.app/MyApp 0x35626f5a
   ```
5. This would show you the exact line, method name which resulted in crash.

   ```
   o/p format : [classname functionName:]; and line number 

   Eg : +[MyController formatMyAddress:] (in MyApp) (MyController.m:401)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Did u view a debug build or release build?
Release builds do not contain all the information about the crash.